# How to implement SIGNED Authorization Type in Gmail Contextual Gadget

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I'm deploying an in-house Gmail contextual gadget from an existing code. Have deployed the gadget in my google apps domain by refering this document : https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/preparing

```
function makeRequest(){
    var params = {};
    params[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.METHOD] = gadgets.io.MethodType.GET;
    params[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.CONTENT_TYPE] = gadgets.io.ContentType.TEXT;
    params[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.AUTHORIZATION] = gadgets.io.AuthorizationType.SIGNED;
    params[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.OAUTH_SERVICE_NAME] = "HMAC";
    params[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.REFRESH_INTERVAL] = 3600;

    var url = "https://applicationid.appspot.com/user/" + sender_name;    
    gadgets.io.makeRequest(url, onResponse, params);
}

function onResponse(response) { 
    if (response.rc != 200) {
        document.getElementById('profile-container').innerHTML = 'Service temporarily unavailable.';
        gadgets.window.adjustHeight();
    } else {
        document.getElementById('profile-container').innerHTML = response.text;
        gadgets.window.adjustHeight();
  }
}
```

But here `response.rc` always returning status code as 500. And  `gadgets.io.makeRequest()` function doesn't make any request to the url (application hosted on appengine). It seems like the issue with `SIGNED Authorization`.  How to implement `SIGNED Authorization` in Gmail Gadget?

Comment: You could find how to implement Signed authorization on the reference: https://developers.google.com/gadgets/docs/reference/

Answer (score 0):

@NNJ - the `OAUTH_SERVICE_NAME` = `HMAC` option is not supported.

You'll need to use the RSA-SHA1 signature method, you can get the certificate from http://opensocialresources.appspot.com/static/igoogle.cert